# Is there some standard way to diagnose a structural time series model (also called simple unobserved components model)?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, kalman-filter, diagnostic, unobserved-components-model

I am dealing with a structural time series model (also called a simple unobserved components model), and I wonder if there is some standard way to diagnose this sort of models. In most reference books the author just compares the series of the forecast and the observed series.

In an example found in Shumway's *Time Series Analysis and Its Applications*, the author seems to calculate the measurement uncertainty (that is, the square root of the noise variance in the measurement equation) and the model uncertainties (i.d. the square roots of model variances corresponding to the trend and seasonal components), and compare these two uncertainties with each other, as shown in the following screenshots. But I did not quite figure out how this worked. It seems to me that the model uncertainties should be as smaller as possible, but the author seems to be satisfied with model uncertainties relatively larger than the measurement uncertianties.

Can anyone explain this to me, or show me some other way of diagnosing structural time series models? May there be some general way to do model diagnosis for all Kalman Filter models? Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cross posted at [Economics SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/51789).